# Unsual behaviour of navigation Menus

Tags: menus, links

I deleted all the previous menus which where there in my site.
Then I created a new menu called Home and added few pages to it

So my menu looks like this[image]

**Problem :** When I click on About us and other links, then that links are not working. Why is this so??

Is it because I deleted all my previous menu? If so then how I can get my deleted menus?

Update:

Error in firebug[image]

Comment: You will have to tell us exactly what you deleted, and how did you add the new items. And why not use custom menus. I recently answered a question on stackoverflow about custom menus, go and check it out in the meantime http://stackoverflow.com/a/22588613/1908141

Comment: Previous menu means the menu which was present after wordpress installation.

Comment: How did you delete the default menu

Comment: By using "Delete menu". Is it because it is https://some site? I have added firebug error.

Comment: There is your problem, you have a syntax error. Please rectify first. In your `wp-config.php`, set `debug` to `true` and work from there

Comment: But I have never touch any config files or any other files. I have used only UI to configure my files. How I can fix that?? And why it arises.

Comment: You have a syntax error, which no can make out from your image. Your problem lies in that syntax error. As said before, set `debug` to `true` in `wp-config.php` It will clearly give you more info on your syntax error. And please post that debugging info in your question

Comment: It was Jquery error. The theme we purchase was not uploaded successfully. hence this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the theme that we purchase didn't upload the plugins and other Java Script files properly

So it was giving an error.
Going through theme installation document helped me.